# Upload an image and JSON/XML from Javascaript/jquery

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, upload

my goal is to upload an image and some extra data in json/xml from javascript/jquery. Since I am currently developing using the PhoneGap framework, this seems to be a bit of an hassle. It does not seem to be a problem doing this separately, but then I kind of loose the relation between the image, and the data that is describing it.

Does anyone have ideas of how to do this? Or some other nice way to "keep the data together"?

Thank you for any suggestions,
OMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u are using Phonegap, you should use the Filetransfer API of it. 
 You could do it like this and send your json object too.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="document";
options.params={};
options.params.fileName = options.fileName ;
options.chunkedMode = true;
options.params.documentDio=dio;//THIS IS YOUR JSON OBJECT
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, uploadUrl, function(data){
   //callback
}, errorFn, options);
```

Comment: Right, thanks! I got the impression at first that this only worked with android from somewhere. But the issue has apparently been fixed in later versions so it also works with iPhone :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the jQuery IFrame plugin:

http://softwareas.com/jquery-iframe-plugin

AJAX communication does not allow multipart data so, the the only two ways I know of are to

- upload file independently of any other data using Flash **OR**
- use this plugin to submit whole form to IFrame, therefore not leaving current page

Hope this helps...

Comment: There is a way to upload a file with Ajax using HTML5 File API.

Comment: I haven't got time to poke around html5 api. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will look into both HTML5, and the iFrame solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

It could also be worth checking out the [Jquery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), this catches the form submit in js and allows you to do whatever with the data before sending it to the server. It works with file uploads too, it uses an iframe approach similar to jperovic's suggestion except that it does it all for you. It's worked well for me in the past.

Comment: I haven't tried but I don't see why it wouldn't! It's very easy to implement so wouldn't take long to have a go.